# JPQL in Google App Engine - Cannot find type of(part of) x since symbol has no type; implicit variable?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpql

I have a web app hosted on Google App Engine with a datastore containing some tables. The table I'm querying is Towns. I want to get all towns of x name. In the datastore, I can see the following columns: ID/Name, date, town.

```
@Entity
public class Town {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    private String Name;
    private String Date;

    // getters, setters
}
```

My query is as follows:

```
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Towns t WHERE t.name LIKE :townName ORDER BY c.date")
    .setParameter("townName", name);

List<Town> townLogs = new ArrayList<Town>(q.getResultList());
```

However, I get the following error:

> org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Cannot find type of (part of) t.name since symbol has no type; implicit variable?

Answer (score 0):

Change the case of **Name** to **name** & **Date** to **date**. That should help you get around the issue that you are facing.

The next issue that you are likely to face is with the implicit reference of "c". That should also ideally be *t.date*

Hope that helps.